# Solution of the form T(x,t) for a non-homogenous differential equation with boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$\frac{\operatorname{d}T}{\operatorname{d}t} =\frac{k}{z} \cdot \ \frac{\operatorname{d}^{2}T}{\operatorname{d}x^{2}} -\frac{\operatorname{d}T}{\operatorname{d}x} + Q \cdot \frac{\sin\left( w \cdot t \right) + 1}{z} $

Where:
$T$: temperature, $x$: distance, $v$: velocity, $t$: time, $z$, $k$, $Q$, $w$: constants

Boundary/initial conditions are:
At the initial time ($t_{0}$) initial temperature ($T_{0}$) = initial fluid temperature
$T\left( \infty,\, t \right) = T\left( -\infty,\, t \right) = T_{0} $ and $T\left( x,\, 0 \right) = T_{0}$

Comment: That is correct! Sorry, for the confusion.

Comment: You can remove the nonhomogeneous part by working with $T' := T - (Q/wz)(\cos wt + t)$.

Comment: Where did you get that from? How do I do that? Do you mean replacing dT/dt with that?

Comment: When I remove the non-homogenous part, how do I add it back?